# Bash: stop variable expansion for function argument

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am trying to write a bash script which has a function for logging:

```
log() {
   echo $1 2>&1
}
```

I checked the output of the following commands:

```
ARCHIVE_PREFIX=$2  // value = myFile
ARCHIVE_FILE_PATTERN="${ARCHIVE_PREFIX}-*.zip" // looking for zip archive starting with my file
log "Searching current directory for pattern - log: $ARCHIVE_FILE_PATTERN"  
echo "Searching current directory for pattern - echo: $ARCHIVE_FILE_PATTERN"
```

I would expect that the last 2 lines to print the same thing, but instead of that the output is:

```
Searching current directory for pattern - log: myFile-08022022.zip // an archive from current working dir
Searching current directory for pattern - log: myFile-*.zip
```

Can someone explain me why this happens and how can I change the logic so that the function will use the actual variable value?

Comment: Quote the `$1`.

Comment: What is `2>&1` supposed to do? When would `echo` print to STDERR?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, *always* quote your parameter expansions, then look for a reason why it shouldn't be quoted. (As opposed to leaving parameter expansions unquote then looking for a reason to quote it.) Most reasons for leaving an expansion unquoted indicate you should use an array instead of a regular parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Biffen said, it's because the `$1` reference in `log` is unquoted. Here's a small example that reproduces the problem:

```sh
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 igstan  staff  0 Mar  9 12:55 bar.md
-rw-r--r--  1 igstan  staff  0 Mar  9 12:55 foo.md
$ PATTERN=*.md
$ echo "$PATTERN"
*.md
$ echo $PATTERN
bar.md foo.md
```

In your case, without quotes, `echo $1` will:

1. expand `$1` to `myFile-*.zip`, which is a [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion-1)
2. expand the glob pattern to *a list* of files that match the pattern
3. echo the list

So the fix is to quote it:

```sh
log() {
  echo "$1" 2>&1
}
```

In addition, I don't think you want to redirect stderr (`2`) to stdout (`1`), but probably the reverse, redirect stdout to stderr so that logging isn't part of the "normal" program output:

```sh
log() {
  echo "$1" 1>&2
}
```

However, if we test it with the previously-declared `PATTERN` variable, we'll see this happening:

```sh
$ log "$PATTERN"
*.md
$ log $PATTERN # glob pattern is expanded before being passed to `log`
bar.md
```

In the second case, only one of the filenames is printed out. This is because the glob expands to *a list* (loosely speaking) of filenames, so if you really want the flexibility to print the entire result, you'd have to swicth from `$1` to `$@` (all the function's arguments) inside the `log` function:

```sh
log() {
  echo "$@" 1>&2
}
```

We now have these results:

```
$ log "$PATTERN"
*.md
$ log $PATTERN # glob pattern is expanded before being passed to `log`
bar.md foo.md
```

Answer (score -1):

the  variable you are trying to print is an array of all the results.
you have to loop through the array to print each element something like this

```
for FILE in $ARCHIVE_FILE_PATTERN
do
log "Searching current directory for pattern - log: $FILE"  
echo "Searching current directory for pattern - echo: $FILE"
done
```

I'm not sure about the syntax of the bash loop but you get the idea  you can rewrite it if this doesn't work.

Comment: ‘_the variable you are trying to print is an array of all the results_’ What makes you say that?!

Comment: the `*` is a wild card character any thing can go there so you will match any thing that has `.md` at the end of it regardless of ho many.

Comment: Sure, but the `ARCHIVE_FILE_PATTERN` variable contains a literal `*`, and it’s _not_ an array.